# Реализация принадлежности координаты полигону на бекенде (Java)

Tags: java, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

В БД есть полигон. Координаты полигона можно отправить из бекенда (Java) в UI и там отобразить на карте.

В UI легко определить принадлежность пары координат широта-долгота принадлежность точки:

```
let coordList =
[
    [
        [55.874258508328104, 37.528900146484375],
        [55.85263463019618, 37.83377075195311],
        [55.69782653563491, 37.913421630859354],
        [55.60930939492386, 37.509674072265604],
        [55.874258508328104, 37.528900146484375]
    ],
    [
        [55.80006915591573, 37.44100952148436],
        [55.758275152726156, 37.78707885742186],
        [55.65747522457113, 37.40805053710937],
        [55.60309011722054, 38.053497314453104],
        [55.80006915591573, 37.44100952148436]
    ]
];

let pol = new ymaps.Polygon(coordList, { ... }, { ... } );
myMap.getObjects.add(pol);
let res = pol.geometry.contains(myTestLat, myTestLon);
// res is boolean
```

Задача усложняется тем, что она содержит внутренние контуры. В примере выше полигон выглядит на карте так:

[image: Карта]

Пробовал понять код функции `contains`, но это невозможно, ибо код в бандле запутан, тем более JS динамически типизирован.

---

**Как определить принадлежность координаты к такого рода полигону?**

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать функцию [within](http://www.tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry.html#within(com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry)) из [Java Topology Suite (JTS)](http://www.tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html)

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vividsolutions/jts -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
    <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
    <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
```

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.LinearRing;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.impl.CoordinateArraySequence;

public class Within {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {

    List<Coordinate> points = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
    points.add(new Coordinate(-5, -5));
    points.add(new Coordinate(-5, 5));
    points.add(new Coordinate(5, 5));
    points.add(new Coordinate(5, -5));
    points.add(new Coordinate(-5, -5));

    GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory(); 
    Polygon polygon = gf.createPolygon(new LinearRing(new CoordinateArraySequence(points.toArray(new Coordinate[points.size()])), gf), null);
    Point point = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(1, 1));

    System.out.println(point.within(polygon));
  }
}
```

---

PS: для js неплохая библиотека для геоинформационного анализа - t[urf.js](https://github.com/Turfjs), там тоже есть [необходимая Вам функция](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/blob/master/packages/turf-boolean-point-in-polygon/index.ts)

PPS: ни то ни другое я не проверял на примере, подобном Вашему, есть подозрение что полигон придется сначала разбить на полигоны [без  самопересечений.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473553/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-self-intersecting-polygon-to-a-multipolygon-in-jts)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473553/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-self-intersecting-polygon-to-a-multipolygon-in-jts